# hide widgets in listView

Tags: android

How is possible to hide/show Layout element in all rows of listView after clicked on button. 
my code

```
Button edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        edit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {          
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hidden);
                if (ll.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else 
                    ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

But it hide only element in first row.

Comment: have you tried with [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a flag, raised or lowered by the click method. Then use this flag in the getView method of your adapter to hide or show views. At the end of the click method, call notifyDataSetChanged to refresh your views.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
   if (lv.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   else 
                lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hide your ListView instead of hiding entire layout.hope it will help you.

Comment: this layout is on ever row in listview, not perent layout of listview.

Comment: try adding your all rows in a list view and hide the entire listview on click event of button.